How does one add or append additional name-value pairs to a form-data object?
How to add an array to the last in this object:
const formElment = document.querySelector(".form");

formElment.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var array = [];
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    array.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    console.log(checkboxes[i].id);
  }

  const formData = new FormData(formElment);
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  
  console.log(data);

});

I used eventlistner for get form data and checkbox=checked. So now I want add those selected checkbox id to the end of the object and send through an API.

Can you include the necessary HTML in your question?

Also, what part of adding the IDs of the selected checkboxes are you having trouble with? What does your attempt to do it look like? What problems did you have with it?

I have contact-us form for get user details like name, mobile number. Also I have a checkbox section there are many programs. I wrote an eventlistner for get both contact us details and user selected programs when submit button click. Now I try add concact details and selected programs into a one single object. Then I can send that to the database

Please see @Reyno's request above. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the [<>] toolbar button); here's how to do one. (Obviously you'd just output the contents of the object at the end rather than trying to send it to a server.)

Why do you not firstly consult a documentation on FormData like e.g the one of MDN. One immediately sees that FormData was designed with a lot of helpers like set or append.

You can add the checkbox values after you have created data using FormData and Object.fromEntries.
Notice that the checkbox elements should not have a name attribute -- then they are not included in the formData object.


const formElment = document.forms.form01;

formElment.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let checkboxes = event.target.checkboxes.elements;

  let formData = new FormData(formElment);
  let data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  data.checkboxes = [...checkboxes]
                      .filter(input => input.checked)
                      .map(input => input.value);
  console.log(data);
});
fieldset {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="something" value="Testing 1 2 3">
  <fieldset name="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>





Why [does the OP] not firstly consult a documentation on FormData like e.g the one of MDN. One immediately sees that FormData was designed with a lot of helpers like set or append.

Since the OP did not provide any example code, the scenario we are going to talk about assumes the presence of both, form-controls which are part of a form and form-controls which do not relate to an own form-element.
In order to append the latter name-value pairs to the form-element related form-data object, one has to target only elements which are not part of a form.
One could achieve this with a combination of a node-list of elements that have been queried by e.g. [type="checkbox"]:checked, where one has to additionally check and filter every control-node for whether it belongs to a form-element ... like e.g. ...
[...document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked')]
  .filter(elm => elm.form === null)

... but one also could come up with a selector which covers that case ... like e.g. ...
const selectCheckedCheckboxWhichIsNotPartOfAForm =
  '[type="checkbox"]:checked:where(:not(:is(form [type="checkbox"])))';

The only thing left is then appending each matching control-node's name-value pair to the form-related form-data object.
... executable example code ...


function handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()

  const elmForm = evt.target;
  const formData = new FormData(elmForm);

  const selectCheckedCheckboxWhichIsNotPartOfAForm =
    '[type="checkbox"]:checked:where(:not(:is(form [type="checkbox"])))';

  document
    .querySelectorAll(selectCheckedCheckboxWhichIsNotPartOfAForm)
    .forEach(elm => formData.append(elm.name, elm.value));

  console.log({
    formDataObject: Object.fromEntries(formData)
  });
}
document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
body { margin: 0; }
form, fieldset { width: 45%; }
form fieldset { width: 100%; }
[type="submit"] { margin: 4px 0 0 2px; }

.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; bottom: 0; top: 8px; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <strong>No-Form</strong> Data
  </legend>

  <label>
    <span>
      foo check
    </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="foo">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>
      bar check
    </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="bar" checked>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form Data</legend>

    <label>
      <span>
        baz value
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="baz" value="baz">
    </label>

    <div>
      <label>
        <span>
          bizz check
        </span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bizz" value="bizz" checked>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>
          booz check
        </span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="booz" value="booz">
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



And in case the OP's following sentence ...

So now I want add those selected checkbox id to the end of the object and send through an API.

... decrypts to something like ...
"I want to append a list which features the id of every checked checkbox."
... the scenario of cause changes. We now assume that only controls are targeted which are checked and which are also members of the very form. The first provided solution then changes to ...


function handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()

  const elmForm = evt.target;
  const formData = new FormData(elmForm);

  // ... create an array of checked checkbox-ids ...
  const checkedIdList =
    [...elmForm.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked')]

      // ... by reducing the above array of queried element-nodes.
      .reduce((result, { id }) => {
        if (!!id) {
          // push only valid/existing `id` values into the array.
          result.push(id);
        }
        return result;
      }, []);

  // - append an additional single key-value pair
  //   where the value is a string that was joined
  //   from the array of valid `id`-values.
  formData.append('checkedIds', checkedIdList.join(','));

  console.log({
    formDataObject: Object.fromEntries(formData)
  });
}
document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 45%; }
label { display: block; }
[type="submit"] { margin: 4px 0 0 2px; }

.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; bottom: 0; top: 8px; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form Data</legend>

    <label>
      <span>
        baz value
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="foo" value="foo">
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>
        bar check
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="bar" id="bar-id">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>
        baz check
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="baz" value="baz" id="baz-id" checked>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>
        bizz check
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bizz" value="bizz" id="bizz-id">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>
        booz check
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="booz" value="booz" id="booz-id" checked>
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




I think you can add the values of array to FormData.
formData.append("checkedValues", array.join(","));
And then you can post your form to your API.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

const formElment = document.querySelector(".form");

formElment.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var array = [];
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  let idobj = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    array.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    console.log(checkboxes[i].id);
    idobj[`id${checkboxes[i].id}`] = checkboxes[i].id    
  }
  
  const formData = new FormData(formElment);
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  Object.assign(data, idobj)
  
  console.log(data);

});

I created a new object for id let idobj = {} and added all the ids idobj[id${checkboxes[i].id}] = checkboxes[i].id.
From my understanding you want to add the ids to data object so I did that
by writing code Object.assign(data, idobj)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
